# Proper usage of ArrayPool<T> with a reference type

Tags: c#, object-pooling

What is the proper way to use ArrayPool with reference types?

I was assuming that it would be full of objects that were just 'newed up' with the default constructor.

For example, in the code below, all the `Foobars` are null when you first rent from the ArrayPool.

**2 Questions:**

1. Since the objects returned from `.Rent` are initially all null, do I need to fill up the array pool with initialized objects first?
2. When returning the rented objects do I need to clear each object?  For example, `foobar.Name = null; foobar.Place = null` etc...

```cs
public class Program
{
    public class Foobar {
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public string Place {get;set;}
        public int Index {get;set;}
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        ArrayPool<Foobar> pool = ArrayPool<Foobar>.Shared;
        var foobars = pool.Rent(5);
        foreach(var foobar in foobars) {
            // prints "true"
            Console.WriteLine($"foobar is null? ans={foobar == null}");
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Since the objects returned from .Rent are initially all null, do I need to fill up the array pool with initialized objects first?

You don't **need** to, no. But you likely should, at least, do `null` checks on anything returned from the array.

> I was assuming that it would be full of objects that were just 'newed up' with the default constructor.

No. They will be `default(T)` - i.e. `null`. It seems like you are thinking of `ArrayPool` as being a pool of objects. That is true, but mainly it is a pool **of arrays**. It is *primarily* trying to avoid the overhead of allocating and de-allocating arrays (not the objects inside the arrays).

> When returning the rented objects do I need to clear each object?

You don't **need** to, no. These is no generic answer as to whether you should or not - that depends on your specific problem space.

When [returning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraypool-1.return?view=netstandard-2.1) to the pool, you can indicate whether the data should be cleared or not. I'd suggest passing `true` as the value of `clearArray` if you don't want your data to be stored in the pool.

> clearArray Boolean
>
> Indicates whether the contents of the buffer should
>   be cleared before reuse. If clearArray is set to true, and if the pool
>   will store the buffer to enable subsequent reuse, the Return(T[],
>   Boolean) method will clear the array of its contents so that a
>   subsequent caller using the Rent(Int32) method will not see the
>   content of the previous caller. If clearArray is set to false or if
>   the pool will release the buffer, the array's contents are left
>   unchanged.

Alternatively, you can take care of clearing the buffer yourself before calling `Return`. I'd also suggest reading [this link](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/27891).

*If you **want** the pool to contain the objects (to avoid the cost of `new`ing them up again) you can do so - but make sure you set `clearArray` to `false` (or leave it at its default).*

Comment: Ok, thank you.  I was thinking `ArrayPool` would be a good way to reduce allocations of objects and was not thinking about minimizing array allocations.  This clears things up.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool/ may be of interest @lifebythedrop .